# Return total rows of multiple models in one controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

sorry for asking sort of easy question but I'd like to clear the confusion of mine. Have been searching the net but mostly works with static models. I am currently trying to find a better way to execute these as the models will be dynamic (new database to work with each week or so) and I just thought there would be a better way instead or iterating the classes. I am new with this framework and really hope if you could spill your ideas to show the better way other than my code below.
I would say raw query is somehow easier but I'd like to use eloquent instead.

```
use App\lifting as data1;
use App\test1 as data2;
use App\test2 as data3;

class dataController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $datas = array(data2::count(), data1::count(), data3::count());

        return $datas;
    }
}
```

Sure it's working and I know it's quite beginner level but you get the idea...

Thanks.

[EDIT]

When I say better way I mean like keeping the models in one collection and just use foreach something like that to get the total rows of each table.

Thanks.

[EDIT 2]

It has been ages. To clarify, I'd solved it already by referring the tables with their respective id (create a new model that stores all the tables) and each time I need a specific table to show up, I'd just refer to its id.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the actual code you have or have you simplified it for your question?

Comment: This is my code.. it's from a controller. You need the full script?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrive count for all the model like below. use models for which you require count & then can get it's count as in the index

> Use Require Model inside controller

```
use App\Models\EmailTemplate;
use App\Models\Enquiry;
use App\Models\User;
```

> Use it in index method to fetch count of required models

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    $enquiryCount = Enquiry::get()->count();
    $emailCount = EmailTemplate::get()->count();
    $userCount = User::get()->count();           

    $data['emailCount'] = $emailCount;
    $data['enquiryCount'] = $enquiryCount;
    $data['userCount'] = $userCount;

   return $data;
}
```

Comment: It still does the same? My main goal is to reduce the models repetitive count() function.. I'll figure another way out.. I am thinking of making a controller which will hold the total row of each table, at each store method I'll make double store, one into the current model and another one to the tablehandler model so I don't have to make all these models with count() anymore and just straight up display **$data->total_rows**. Thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

use [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

exemple:

```
$users = User::withCount(['comments'])->get();
```